# How to get the name with highest score in bash?

Tags: bash

I tried to write bash code to get the name with the highest score.
The data is like this:

```
Name  Score
a     63
b     95
c     56
```

So I sort the file first, then print the second line of the first column

```
sort -rk 2 -n names.csv
awk 'NR == 2{print $1}' names.csv
```

But the program does not give me any result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all this in a single line.

```
$ sort -rk 2 -n name.csv
b     95
a     63
c     56
Name  Score           
$ sort -rk 2 -n names.csv | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
b
```

Answer (score 0):

sort normally sends its output to console, so either use output redirection or a pipe.

Redirection is:

```
sort -rk -2 names.csv > sorted.csv
awk '{NR=2 print $1}' sorted.csv
```

However using a pipe is more elegant, especially if you don't want to keep **sorted.csv** ( it would need a third command to delete it ).

Done this way:

```
    sort -rk -2 names.csv | awk '{NR=2 print $1}'
```

Simples !

Comment: Thank you. I tried to using a pipe, but the outcome is still null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut

```
sort -rk 2 -n names.csv | cut -f1 -d' ' | head -n1
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: I don't understand too.